# Make folder hidden after Inno Setup installs it

Tags: inno-setup, file-attributes

My application has a folder of files that are all marked as "hidden" (including the folder itself). However, Inno Setup won't copy them for installation unless I remove the "hidden" attribute first.

Fair enough, but is there a way to make Inno Setup mark the installed folder as "hidden" after it finishes setup on my end-user's machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

See the `Attribs` parameter for entries in the `[Dirs]` section.

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\blah"; Attribs: hidden;
```

Note that this won't really stop people from seeing it, just make it look like you have something to hide.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ensure that ONLY the directory is hidden, and not the subdirectory. Say its name is *srcHiddenDir*.
Now, create another directory *dstHiddenDir*, but dont make it hidden now. But it should be empty.

Then, open the settings.json, and replace all the occurrences of *srcHiddenDir* with *dstHiddenDir*.

Now, Make it ready to copy files as usual. In one part of the code, you will get:

```
[Files]

Source: "wherethewholecodeis\phpdesktop\phpdesktop-chrome.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "wherethewholecodeis\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "wherethewholecodeis\*srcHiddenDir*\*"; DestDir: "{app}\*dstHiddenDir*"; Attribs:hidden; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Then, you need to write:

```
[Dirs]
Name: {app}\dstHiddenDir; Attribs:hidden;
Name: {app}\dstHiddenDir\application; Attribs:hidden;
Name: {app}\dstHiddenDir\database; Attribs:hidden;
Name: {app}\dstHiddenDir\css; Attribs:hidden;
....
```

...and all the subdirectories you want to hide, just for more safety. But **Note** those subdirectories should be genuine, and there in the source/destination. Else, when you run the setup, error will show that these directories dont exist.

Now, compile the program.
Hope this helps.